# Creating a non-binary tree structure in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic, tree

I need help creating a non-binary tree structure. This structure must contain a class `node` with as many pointers to node as a the node needs. This is where I get confused.

Here is my class `node`:

```
class nodo{
public:
    int id;
    char info[255];
    nodo **son,*father;
    nodo()
    {
        strcpy(info,"");
        son=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    }
};
```

As far as I understand, each time I need a new `son` pointer I must do the following code:

```
son=(nodo*)realloc(sizeof(nodo)*t)
```

`t` being the number of nodes I want to add plus 1. I can´t seem to understand how to access the pointers. For example, I've already added 2 `sons` and I want to access the second one, how should I do it?

Is there any other approach to the problem?

Any help will be thanked.

Comment: Nope, realloc takes 2 arguments: the previous pointer and the new *total* size including new and old elements. Also, `**son` means son is a pointer to a pointer not a pointer directly to a node.

Also, why would you automatically create a "son" when you create a node? Surely you only add sons to the node when it needs them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing C++, not C. Don't try to re-implement your own dynamic array from the ground up. The standard library already has `std::vector` to handle that for you.

```
class nodo{
public:
    int id;
    std::string info;
    nodo *parent;
    std:::vector<nodo *> children;

    nodo(nodo *parent) : parent(parent)
    {
    }

    void add_child(nodo *child) { children.push_back(child); }
};
```

Comment: Since you are mentioning features of the C++ standard library, why not go a step further and use smart pointers here, if this is indeed a use case where they are useful ?

Comment: @SirDarius: Because there's not enough information here to be at all sure it's the case.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Just a quick doubt though.
When I add a new children how do I go about it?
Any good vector tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to dynamically create an array of child pointers for each node. This approach is fine as long as you know how many children the node will have beforehand.

Your constructor should look something like this:

```
nodo(int numsons) {
   son = new nodo*[numsons];
}
```

This will allocate an array of child nodes, which you will need to delete in the deconstructor.

If you don't know how many children the node will have beforehand (when you call the constructor), you should use a vector.